# SQL query with optional oposite where conditions

Tags: php

I want to make optional sql query parameters, problem is when both `$param['a']` and `$param['b']` are true. Then the $query would look like this `SELECT * from table WHERE something = TRUE AND column IS NOT NULL AND column IS NULL)`. How can I solve this ?

```
switch($param)
{
  case $param['a']:
    $query = "AND column IS NOT NULL";
  case $param['b']:
    $query = "AND column IS NULL";
}
```

Comment: use if elseif conditions

Comment: That could work but if I have let's say 5 parameters then I will need a lot of combinations

Comment: You can add a `default` case. And you also need to `break;` in each statement, otherwise it might give unexpected results.

Comment: Your question is confusing.  What do you WANT to happen when both params are true?  What do the params mean?

Comment: When both parameters are used, then I want to negate the optional query, so that it will behave as it was not there. But this is just example, I can have 5 parameters for example, and many possible combinations so I want something that will handle situation when two conditions are oposite so it behave like the condition is not set.

Answer (score 0):

Replace your switch with if conditions.

By using if condition and concatenation you can achieve the desired query. For example if you have two parameters

Lets you initial query is

```
$query = 'SELECT * from table WHERE something = TRUE';
// based on the params concate conditions to initial query 
if($param['a']){
    $query .= ' AND column IS NOT NULL';
}
if($param['b']){
    $query .= ' AND column IS NULL';
}
```

if both the param are true the result query will be

```
SELECT * from table WHERE something = TRUE AND column IS NOT NULL AND column IS NULL
```

You can add as many conditions as required based on your parameters.

Comment: That won't work, because if column is NULL and columns is NOT NULL then it will always fail.

Comment: oh that's my misunderstanding. I thought the column is different for each param. I could not think any solution other than using if and elseif conditions.